# Flask - How to change the directory of the templates folder?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to change the directory of my Flask Templates folder. I have tried this:

```
template_dir = os.path.abspath('../website/endpoint')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)
@app.route("/api/t-tycoon/sotd")
def tt_sotd():
return render_template("sotd.html")
```

This code, however, creates the following error:

```
return render_template("sotd.html")
```

Another handy thing to have is the directories, so here you have it.

```
main.py
website
   endpoint
      sotd.html
   jsons
```

I have no clue what is wrong, and how this works. I read some things online about changing the Flask directory but it does not work.

If more information is needed, please let me know. I hope someone can help me figure this, as I have no clue myself.

Error: *jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: sotd.html*

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: If this refers to the title of the HTML redirect site with the error, I have this:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
(jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: sotd.html)

Comment: template_dir = os.path.abspath('website/endpoint') try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your templates subdirectory next to the python module (the module where you create your Flask app- main.py in your example):

```
main.py
templates_subdirectory
    sotd.html
```

Move your template (sotd.html) to 'website' directory and configure it to be your templates subdirectory, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using is wrong. As @NavaneethaKrishnan said it should be `os.path.abspath('website/endpoint')`.

However this solution is not perfect either. `website/endpoint` is still a relative path and it is relative to your current working directory. As a result it will only work if your current working directory is the one `main.py` lives in.

A better solution is:

```py
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
template_dir = os.path.join(dir_path, "website/endpoint")
```

Here `dir_path` is the absolute path of the directory under which `main.py` lives in. By concatenating `dir_path` and `website/endpoint`, your template directory is guaranteed to be the one you've created and it will be irrelevant with your current working directory.